# What is the Windows equivalent of `__attribute__((weak))`?

Tags: c++, windows, weak-symbol

I'm trying to port a GNU project to Windows and I ran across the following GNU syntax...

```
extern void serialEventRun(void) __attribute__((weak));
```

What is the Windows equivalent to this, or how does Windows handle [weak symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)?

Comment: This is not a Windows thing, it is a feature of your C++ linker. I assume you're using Visual Studio?

Comment: __declspec(selectany) might do what you want